# Unable to find resource 'opensymphony:quartz-all:pom:1.6.3' in repository central

Tags: maven, quartz-scheduler

I inherited this project which used to build & run successfully (years ago...). Now when checked out from version control, as is, it complains:

> Unable to find resource 'opensymphony:quartz-all:pom:1.6.3' in
>   repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

But following that repository link (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) leads to a browsable site that shows clearly that this resource **is** available: http://search.maven.org/#browse|1030701351 !

I have even been able to manually download it, and I can also find it in my local repo (`C:\maven\repo\opensymphony\quartz-all\1.6.3\quartz-all-1.6.3`).

So, my questions:

1. Why is Maven complaining at all, if it *is* there?
2. How did it get to my local [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13496645/1864054), if Maven couldn't find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local repository is NOT in C:\maven ... it is in your users directory ~/.m2/repository

To debug what is really going on I would suggest to deactivate the ~/.m2/settings.xml (e.g. by renaming it) and do a clean build without any of the old artifacts and from a fresh local repository (just delete ~/.m2/repository)

That would tell you what is really missing.

If anything is missing that means it is not in the Centra Repository (http://search.maven.org). As a next step I would then install a repository manager in your network. I would recommend using Sonatype Nexus (open source, free book as documentation) and then add any other repositories or missing artifacts in there.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I actually found the `~/.m2/repository` you are referring to and it contains as expected a cache of the packages the make the dependency list in my project's `pom.xml`. But I also found `~/.m2/settings.xml` which contains a `<localRepository>` entry to points to **another** local repository. How does that reconcile? Does that mean that I have *two* local repositories?

Comment: Also, any idea what could be reasonable explanations for the phenomena I am seeing (i.e. answers to the 2 questions in my OP)? +1 for now.

Comment: Updated answer with further tips

Comment: Thanks! I did just as you suggested and the result was educating: The build ended up successfully (not a single package missed in the new repo), but Maven reported "Unable to find" quite a few packages on http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/ only to download them immediately after that from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ . **How does that work?** I still don't have answers to my 2 original questions but I am accepting your answer as it has been very educating to me.

Comment: well.. maven was complaining because it did not find it due to a misconfigured environment (settings.xml and repo location)

Comment: And how did it get into the repo folder.. no idea. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I think I finally got the answer to the 2nd question (*"how did it get there"*): There is a **hierarchy** of repositories (local, central, remote, [more](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-remote-repository-in-maven-pom-xml/)?). The fact that it complained about not finding it in one, doesn't necessarily mean that it didn't find it in another down the chain. All is well now.

Comment: Just please keep in mind that it is bad practice to add repositories to the pom.xml ...