# Why am I getting this dependency resolution error in my pom.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, pom.xml, atmosphere

I am getting the following error when I try and build my web app -

> Failed to execute goal on project MyApp: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.myapp:MyApp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could
>   not find artifact
>   org.atmosphere.samples:atmosphere-jaxrs2-chat:jar:1.0.5 in primefaces
>   (http://repository.primefaces.org/) -> [Help 1]

Here's the repositories and dependencies sections of my pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
        <id>primefaces</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces 3.2</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>              
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere.samples</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-jaxrs2-chat</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't understand why it is looking for the artifact org.atmosphere.samples:atmosphere-jaxrs2-chat:jar:1.0.5 in the primefaces repository? Why doesn't it just pull it from the central maven repository? I thought that repository is automatically used by default?

It seems to have no problem with the atmosphere-runtime artifact so I don't understand why the other atmosphere artifact is causing this problem?

Comment: I went through a similar experience until I deleted `~/.m2/repository` per @ManfredMoser's [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13922612/1864054). Perhaps this could help in your case too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That version of the artifact is not in the maven repository, at least not with that group and artifact id... Last version in maven central repo is 1.0.1 as you can see [**here**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.atmosphere.samples/atmosphere-jaxrs2-chat)