# Unresolved dependecies when changing from Grails 2.1.1 to Grails 2.4.4

Tags: tomcat, grails, ggts

I have imported a project in Eclipse (GGTS) based on Grails 2.1.1 and need to update it to version 2.4.4. I am using Windows 7 with a 32 bit-Eclipse version (Kepler).

When checking the dependencies, I am getting the following errors:

```
    Starting process on CARMBEL11628/10.113.134.246
Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
|Downloading: D:\Programme\grails-2.4.4\plugins\tomcat-7.0.55.pom
|Downloading: D:\Programme\grails-2.4.4\plugins\tomcat-7.0.55.zip
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    Host repo.grails.org not found. url=https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55/tomcat-7.0.55-sources.jar
    Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55/tomcat-7.0.55-sources.jar
    Host repo.grails.org not found. url=https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55/tomcat-7.0.55-src.jar
    Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55/tomcat-7.0.55-src.jar
    Host repo.grails.org not found. url=https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55/tomcat-7.0.55-javadoc.jar
    Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55/tomcat-7.0.55-javadoc.jar
    Host repo.grails.org not found. url=https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.55.pom
    Host repo.grails.org not found. url=https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.55.jar
    Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.55.pom
    Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.55.jar
        module not found: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.55
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
```

....

```
        ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.pom
      -- artifact org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler#ecj;3.7.2!ecj.jar:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.55: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.55: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.55: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.55: not found
        :: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-websocket;7.0.55: not found
        :: org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler#ecj;3.7.2: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Any ideas how to solve the error messages? I found several advices of how to change the BuildConfig.groovy (build ':tomcat:7.0.55' instead of build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"). Moreover, I deleted the Ivy-cache.

Thanks,

Best

Comment: Have you tried creating a new app in 2.4.4 then ammending the BuildConfig to include your plugins ? My suggestion would be to do 1 entry at a time and DO check grails plugins to ensure you are running latest version of each of the plugins you define.. This will ensure you catch the problem with which ever plugin is the culprit

Comment: Yes, I integrated the files in a new project...without success.

Comment: so a brand new project under 2.4.4 i.e. grails create-app something then inside app grails run-app does not work ?

Comment: I first need to integrate the external libraries...that is my current problem. Refresh dependencies does not work.

Comment: I think you are over complicating things. What do you mean by external libraries?  - I suggest you create a default app if grails run-app works - then forget your app for now. Create a new app under 2.4.4 using its defaults - go through your plugins in your old app - look up grails get latest add them 1 by 1 refresh dependencies on each --- make sure all of that is working once your BuildConfig compiles WITH NO CONTENT - then copy the grails-app folder across excluding conf/BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: I need Tomcat, postgres, jboss and other libraries, specified in BuildConfig, I never had a working app (also not with old version 2.1.1) as I imported this project. I can't use Grails 2.1.1, so I never could test the app. When trying to set up a new Grails project and integrating the files, I just receice the same errors...

Answer (score 7):

You didn't say whether you are behind a corporate proxy - if you are then this may help you:
http://grails.org/wiki/2.4.4%20Release%20Notes says (near end) that Grails 2.4.4 defaults to https for grailsCentral() and mavenCentral().

There seems to be an unresolved bug in maven 3.0.4 relating to proxies https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11841 so I just wondered whether my corporate proxy was blocking the https...

I made these changes in my BuilConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
```

in repositories:

```
//grailsPlugins()   // Only for Ivy
//grailsHome()      // Only for Ivy
//mavenLocal()      // Only for Ivy
//grailsCentral()   // As of Grails 2.4.4 this defaults to https
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
//mavenCentral()    // As of Grails 2.4.4 this defaults to https 
mavenRepo "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your grails repo.

```
repositories {
   grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugins"
}
```

for details visit link.
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Plugin-publication-migration-HOWTO-td4474812.html

and read this for maven repo.
[Unable to find resource in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479413/unable-to-find-resource-in-repository-central-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2)

Comment: Instead of mavenLocal() and mavenCentral()?    Currently, my BuildConfig looks like:   repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral() }

Comment: Sadly, I am getting the same error messages...I am also having similar problems with javassist, postgres, hibernate-validator, cache-core, jboss-logging, jquery, resources and liquibase-core....

Comment: I can't post the content of the file here...as I am getting error messages although I tried to post it in snippets...not my day.