# Why would pom.xml fail to find Maven repository?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, vertica

I need to use [this repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vertica/vertica-jdbc/9.1.1) from maven central for my application. But my application is failing to locate it. I use IntelliJ Idea and the Sync window gives me error -

```
Could not find artifact com.vertica:vertica-jdbc:pom:9.1.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

This is how my pom.xml looks like -

[image]

Can anyone please let me know how can i configure my application so it can locate this `vertica jdbc driver` from maven central repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find resource in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479413/unable-to-find-resource-in-repository-central-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2)

Comment: As you can see in the linked duplicate ticket the problem is that mvnrepository.com is an aggregator of many repo's it also shows the hint below the dependency:

"Note: this artifact it located at ICM repository (http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/)"

Comment: See https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/239404/vertica-9-driver-in-maven-repository about how you can download and install the jdbc driver into local Maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no `pom` nor `jar` for this artifact and version, in the maven central, only the `sources`.
This is why it can't find it.

You can download it here https://www.vertica.com/client-drivers/

Comment: i've downloaded and ran the command: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=opt/vertica/java/lib/vertica-jdbc-9.1.1-0.jar -DgroupId=com.vertica -DartifactId=vjdbc9 -Dversion=9.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
and got java.sql.SQLException: jdbc:vertica://rnd-vt1.dev1.com:5433/en