# Cannot resolve com.vertica:vertica-jdbc:9.0.1

Tags: maven, docker, jdbc, vertica

I'm trying to use a vertica driver with my Maven application.
Here is a snapshot of my pom.xml:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>icm</id>
            <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vertica</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertica-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

but i'm getting the error `Cannot resolve com.vertica:vertica-jdbc:9.0.1`
I'm not sure what i'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Maybe it's worth noting that i intend to run this with Docker. I've tried local install of the driver and it works. I've tried local install in Docker with the command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=opt/vertica/java/lib/vertica-jdbc-9.1.1-0.jar -DgroupId=com.vertica -DartifactId=vjdbc9 -Dversion=9.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and i get this below error:

```
Java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:vertica://rnd-vt1.dev1.com:5433/en
```

Here is my simple java application that i indend to use

```
public class TestConnection {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties myProp = new Properties();
    myProp.put("user", "admin1");
    myProp.put("password", "1234");
    Connection conn;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:vertica://rnd-vt1.dev1.com:5433/en", myProp);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE id = 1";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would pom.xml fail to find Maven repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496004/why-would-pom-xml-fail-to-find-maven-repository)

Comment: as it's mentioned there the artifact is located in the ICM repository, which is why i have that in my repositories tag

Comment: Read Arnaud's answer in linked thread - there is neither jar nor pom in ICM repo, only source code. You can visit http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/com/vertica by yourself - it will give you 404.

Comment: You probably need to download this driver from Vertica website and attach it to your artifact

Comment: You have installed the driver with artifactId `vjdbc9` and version `9.1.1`, not artifactId `vertica-jdbc` with version `9.0.1`